# Why replace substring does not work in Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I try to replace everywhere the symbols `" -` in the start line and end line:

```
dtnew.applymap(lambda x: x.replace('^-', ''))
dtnew.applymap(lambda x: x.replace('^"', ''))
```

But the output dataframe has these symbols

Comment: try `dtnew.str.replace('^-', '')`

Comment: `DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'

Comment: And this also does not work: `df[df.columns] = df.apply(lambda x: str(x).strip())`

Comment: `dtnew.replace('^[-"]', '', regex = TRUE)`

Comment: Does not work: `df.replace('^[-"]', '', regex = True)` I can show type of columns, maybe it works only for string

Answer (score 2):

well, if performance is NOT an issue you can iterate over columns and rows and use a simple replace (see below). Again, I would only use this if the dataframe is not enormous and you have no concern for performance.

```
for column in df.columns:
    for i in df.index:    
        df[column][i] = df[column][i].replace('-','').replace('"','')
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this example and that you only want to replace the leading character(s):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['- abc', 'def -'], ['" ghi-', '--jkl']])

        0      1
0   - abc  def -
1  " ghi-  --jkl
```

Use [`str.lstrip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.lstrip.html).

```
df2 = df.apply(lambda c: c.str.lstrip('- "'))
```

output:

```
      0      1
0   abc  def -
1  ghi-    jkl

# as list: [['abc', 'def -'], ['ghi-', 'jkl']]
```

For only the first character, use [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
df2 = df.apply(lambda c: c.str.replace('^[- "]', '', regex=True))
```

output:

```
       0      1
0    abc  def -
1   ghi-   -jkl

# as list: [[' abc', 'def -'], [' ghi-', '-jkl']]
```

##### generalization:

- to strip both start and end, use [`str.strip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html)
- to remove all characters (anywhere): `df.apply(lambda c: c.str.replace('[- "]', '', regex=True))`
- to remove first or last matching character: `df.apply(lambda c: c.str.replace('(^[- "]|[- "]$)', '', regex=True))`